# no apache2 folder under my etc folder, very confused? etc/apache2?

Tags: apache, server

I'm using an aws ec2 server and trying to change a configuration file to allowoverride in the path /etc/apache2/sites-available

however, under the folder etc, there exists no apache2. Does anyone know why? Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Which Linux flour you are using? if its Redhat or Amazon Linux,  name should be httpd and path would be like /etc/httpd , in the debian based Linux folder name is apache2